# Trouble calcualting simple limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm not sure if my solution is correct. The limit is:
$\lim_{x\to0}\cot(x)-\frac{1}{x}$. Here is how I tried to solve it:
 1. $\lim_{x\to0}\cot(x)-\frac{1}{x}$ = $\lim_{x\to0}\cot(x) - x^{-1}$
 2. Since $\cot(0)$ is not valid, apply the de l'Hôpital rule  $(\cot (x) )' = -\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}=\sin^{-2} x $ and $(x^{-1})'$ = $x^{-2}$ 
 3. $\lim_{x\to0}\sin^{-2} (x)-x^{-2} = 0 - 0 = 0$ 
However I'm not sure that my logic is correct

Comment: no, it's not correct

Comment: (1) ....$(x^{-1})'=-x^{-2},$ not $+x^{-2}$.... (2) Neither $(\sin x)^{-2}$ nor $x^{-2}$ converges to $0$ as $x\to 0$....(3). $\lim_{x\to 0} ((\sin  x)^{-2}-x^{-2})=-1/3$...(4) l'Hopital's rule is for a RATIO of two functions, not their difference.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\cot(x)-\frac1x=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}-\frac1x=\frac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x\sin(x)}$$

Now try L'Hospital's rule, as it is now of the form $0/0$.

Comment: I got it. However, I don't understand is it necessary to have $0/0$ or $\infty /\infty $ to apply L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: yes It is one of the hypotheses of Theorem

Comment: @nameLess Yes, you need that to do L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, $\tan x \sim x$ for small $x$ by Taylor's yields $\cot x\sim 1/x$ which should make the limit pretty easy.

To apply L'Hôpital's I always convert it to the indeterminate form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ to avoid mistakes. Although you are justified in applying L'Hôpital's in this case as $\infty-\infty$ is an indeterminate form.

Comment: The implementation of L'Hopital's isn't correct however

Comment: @ZacharySelk possible, I did not check this. My apologies

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} cot(x)-x^{-1} &= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x\cos (x)-\sin(x)}{x\sin(x)} \\
&= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(x)-x\sin(x)-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+x\cos(x)}, \text{      L'Hôpital's}
\\
&= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-x\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+x\cos(x)}
\\
&= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-\sin(x)-x \cos(x)}{\cos(x)-x\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\text{,      L'Hôpital's}
\\&=0
\end{align}